# condition inside [hidden]=" arr[0],arr[1],arr[2]== var " in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to do confirmation.The first thing is the user input that is in form of array that is binded to `[(ngModel)]` so that I can use it for confirm validation further, i.e  1st input is [(ngModel)]="pin[0]" , 2nd input `[(ngModel)]="pin[1]"` and 3rd input is `[(ngModel)]="pin[2]"`.

**Code:**

```
<input type="text" pattern="^([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-5])+$" id="1" style="width: 38px;" [(ngModel)]="pin[0]" maxlength="2" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="next(pin[0], 2, 1)" #zero name="GST_0" preventCutCopyPaste>
    -&nbsp;-
<input type="text" id="2" maxlength="10" pattern="([a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1})" style="width: 110px;" [(ngModel)]="pin[1]" autocomplete="off" [disabled]="!pin[0]" (keyup)="next(pin[1], 10, 2)" #one name="GST_1" preventCutCopyPaste>
    -&nbsp;-
<input type="text" id="3" [(ngModel)]="pin[2]" pattern="^(1-9a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]{1})" maxlength="3" style="width: 45px;" autocomplete="off" [disabled]="!pin[1]" (keyup)="next(pin[2], 2, 3)" #two name="GST_2" preventCutCopyPaste> 
    &nbsp;
<input type="text" id="form1"  [(ngModel)]="GST_number2"  maxlength="15" class="form-control"  name="GST_number2"  #confirmgst="ngModel" ngModel required preventCutCopyPaste>

<label> Confirm GST Number </label>
<div *ngIf="confirmgst.touched" style="color:red"  [hidden]="GST_number2 == pin[0],pin[1],pin[2],"> 
    GST number do not match!
</div>
```

Comment: how you want validate it?

Comment: [hidden] = " this ==  this "  then true

Comment: i mean what should be valid??

Comment: 1st this is like 3 inputs pin[0],pin[1] and pin[2] and 2nd this is GST_number2

Comment: I am sry there is no validation .Only confirmation like if this ==  this then confirmed

Comment: Did you mean `GST_number2 == pin[0]+pin[1]+pin[2]`?

Comment: Yes I didn't knew we could concatenate inside condition. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdsgqs)

```
<input type="text" pattern="^([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-5])+$" id="1" style="width: 38px;" [(ngModel)]="pin[0]" maxlength="2"
 autocomplete="off" (keyup)="next(pin[0], 2, 1)" #zero name="GST_0" preventCutCopyPaste>-&nbsp;-

<input type="text" id="2" maxlength="10" pattern="([a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1})" style="width: 110px;" [(ngModel)]="pin[1]"
 autocomplete="off" [disabled]="!pin[0]" (keyup)="next(pin[1], 10, 2)" #one name="GST_1" preventCutCopyPaste>-&nbsp;-

<input type="text" id="3" [(ngModel)]="pin[2]" pattern="^(1-9a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]{1})" maxlength="3" style="width: 45px;"
 autocomplete="off" [disabled]="!pin[1]" (keyup)="next(pin[2], 2, 3)" #two name="GST_2" preventCutCopyPaste> &nbsp;



<input type="text" placeholder="GST_2" id="form1" [(ngModel)]="GST_number2" maxlength="15" class="form-control" name="GST_number2"
 #confirmgst="ngModel" ngModel required preventCutCopyPaste>


<label> Confirm GST Number  </label>


<div *ngIf="confirmgst.touched" style="color:red" [hidden]="GST_number2== pin[0]+pin[1]+pin[2]
 "> GST number do not match!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this condition `GST_number2 == pin[0]+pin[1]+pin[2]`

```
<div *ngIf="confirmgst.touched" style="color:red" [hidden]="GST_number2 == pin[0]+pin[1]+pin[2]"> 
   GST number do not match!
</div>
```